# show more data from database using php-ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I made a button from some Youtube tutorials and edited some of the code to work with my database. I am making a website show 24 images when the website loads and when the user clicks on a "show more" button, load 10 more images. So now, the 24 images are showing but when I click on the "show more" button nothing happens. The weird thing is when I click on other buttons like "close modal" this happens:

[the close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AuR4.png)

[before clicking on close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGo5O.png)

[after clicking on close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE368.png)

I have no idea why

The close button code:

```
<button style='color:white' type='button' class='btn btn-default bg-custm' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
```

here is ajax script image counting

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var wallsCount = 24;
        $("#bu").click(function(){
          wallsCount = wallsCount + 10;
            $("#walls").load("iph-art-load.php", {
              wallsNewCount : wallsCount
            });
        });
      });

  </script>
```

code for showing database image

```
        <div id="walls">
       <?php  

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `iph-art` LIMIT 24";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row ['walls'];

      }

        }else{
       echo "There are no Wallpapers at this time";
    }
            ?>


    </div>
 <br>
```

the Show more button code

```
<button id="bu" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Show more wallpapers</button>
```

iph-art-load.php code

```
      <?php 

  include 'dbh.php';


   $wallsNewCount = $_POST['wallsNewCount'];


         $sql = "SELECT * FROM `iph-art` LIMIT $wallsNewCount";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo $row ['walls'];    
      }

       }else{
      echo "There are no Wallpapers at this time";
   }



    ?>
```

**the console error**

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**Expected behavior:**

The website shows 24 images from a database on the web-page. The "show more" button displays 10 more images.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

on my **iph-art.php** page.